Dynamic parameter value change in Power BI desktop does not update the chosen value immediately
I have created dynamic parameter for say the field Year. The parameter is created with a list of different years the users can choose from. The users view the report from Power BI desktop directly. Power BI service is not used. The dynamic parameter is created in power query--> "enable load" checked for the parameter. I can now see and use this parameter in the report View--> Transform data--> edit parameters(screenshot attached). For instance, the default year is set to 2023 and the user selects 2024 from this dynamic parameter. The report data gets refreshed as soon as they select. however, i have also created a Card Visual for them to see on the report display to show which year they have selected.
That card value is what remains the same until the main 'refresh' option is clicked on the report view. The want the year value on the card visual to change immediately upon the change in dynamic parameter value just like the report data gets updated immediately.
Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated.
Regards,
